# exportar excel utilizando filtro de fecha en c#

Tags: c#, excel

Puedo exportar a excel información de la tabla "DetalleRecepcion", pero quisiera filtrar por fecha de emisión lo exportado, el problema es que este campo se encuentra en la tabla "Recepcion".

Realizo esto y se exporta a excel, que debería agregar para filtrarlo por fechas?

> [image: Cita en bloque]

Este es mi formulario:

> [image: Cita en bloque]

Comment: 1) Colocar el codigo, no la imagen del codigo. 2) Por cual fecha se va a filtrar: "fecharige" o "fechadocumento" ? Que nombre tienen los datepicker en los que el usuario selecciona las fechas por los cuales va a filtrar?

Comment: Presta atención a la recomendación que te hacen. Nadie te va a responder con una imagen para que la transcribas, no pongas a los demás a transcribir. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Answer (score 0):

Asumiendo que sabés cómo hacer llegar las 2 fechas a tu código del servidor (llamemos a estas variables "*fechaDesde*" y "*fechaHasta*"), filtrar luego los datos a exportar en función de ese rango de fechas es sencillo. Podés usar LINQ, que es muy práctico para eso.

Primero, convertimos tu objeto `DataRowCollection` a un tipo más fácil de trabajar, una colección de `DataRow` :

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> rows = dd.Rows.Cast<DataRow>();
```

Ahora la variable `rows` contiene a todas las filas que originalmente tenía tu objeto `dd.Rows` , y a esta nueva variable al ser del tipo `IEnumerable` , podemos aplicarle cualquier función de LINQ para trabajar sobre sus elementos. Por ejemplo..

```
rows = rows.Where(x => x.["fecharige"] >= fechaDesde && x.["fecharige"] <= fechaHasta).ToList();
```

¡Y listo ! Ahí filtramos los elementos que teníamos en rows por el subconjunto de datos que coincida con el filtro que se aplicó. Dicho sea de paso, asumí la columna "*fecharige*" es por la que querías filtrar, pero si es otra columna tan sólo deberías cambiarlo allí.

Finalmente, iterá sobre esta nueva colección (y no sobre la original de `dd.Rows`):

```
foreach(DataRow fila in rows)
{
  // tu código ..
}
```

Si te sirvió, marcá la respuesta como correcta. ¡Gracias!  :=)

Comment: GRACIAS MATIAS, ME SIRVIÓ TU RESPUESTA!, PUDE GENERAR EL FILTRO, TE AGRADESCO.

Comment: De nada @GuillermoDiazSalinas !! me alegro haberte podido ayudar.

Comment: @GuillermoDiazSalinas si te sirvió para solucionar tu problema, por favor no olvides marcar la respuesta como correcta.